# Flutter Hive DB not working in background

Tags: flutter, hive

I'm trying to save data using Hive while app running it's working fine but while app in background it's not work,
Btw all the data is primitive.

I try to save them using sharedpref but also I have got the same result.so what can I do now ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.